# How to print a quoted sexp using '... (reader syntax) instead of using (quote ...)?

Tags: elisp, functions, quote, print

The result of `(print 'foo)` is `(quote foo)`. Is there a similar function whose result is `'foo`, which is what people generally write?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C-h v print-quoted`:

> **`print-quoted`** is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means print quoted forms with reader syntax.
>   I.e., `(quote foo)` prints as `'foo`, `(function foo)` as `#'foo`.